# Number of times an object gets sampled when sampling $N$ times with replacement from $M$ objects

Tags: probability, multinomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

Take $N$ draws with replacement from $M$ unique objects.  As $N$ goes up, what is the distribution over the increment to the number of times I get each $M$?

So say $M$ is 3 and $N$ is one.  The distribution would have 66% of its mass on zero and 33% of its mass on one, because any given object is going to get picked one third of the time.

Add one to $N$.  This distribution would then be over the domain zero to two.  But I've always found probability unintuitive and could use some help thinking through what the actual distribution should be.

Is there a convenient function for this in R or Python?

What I'm after is a distribution -- as a function of $M$ and $N$ -- of the number of times any given $m \in M$ gets repeated.  So like when you bootstrap you get about .38 zeros and .62 nonzeros.  How should I break out that .62 into the expected number of ones, twos, threes, etc, as M and N change?

Comment: Could you please explain and clarify what "distribution over the increment" might mean?  Note that a multinomial distribution describes a *multivariate* random variable and therefore its CDF is a function of multiple real values: it's not a function of a single real variable.

Comment: @whuber By "distribution over the increment" I guess I just mean the difference between the pmf at N rolls and the pmf at N+1 rolls.  Ideally there would be a way to compute this without computing the multinomial pmf twice and then subtracting.

Comment: @whuber I think I'm realizing that I'm not exactly looking for the distribution of times that each of $M$ objects gets picked.  I want to know the distribution of the number of times each of the $M$ objects gets repeated.  I'll clarify the question.  IDK if what I'm after is a multinomial CDF.

Comment: @whuber please take the hold off